# Is there a way to implement or use Invokes/Threadings in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, invokerequired

First of all: I'm very new to Xamarin, so this might sound quite stupid. I need to "rewrite" a c#-programm to Xamarin (as in: I programmed an Computerprogramm and I now have to write an android-app for it. I'm using Android-App(Xamarin).). So far, so good, but I'm having problems with the Threading - MethodInvoker, InvokeRequire, etc. How can I deal with it?
I kinda hope that there are simpler ways than asynchron tasks for it, given that asyn. task are an alternative?

For example this short code:

```
void setMessage(Messages.Message m)
            {
                MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate ()
                { ML.Add(m); }; // add list item to list ML
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);
                }
                else
                    methodInvokerDelegate();
            }
```

Comment: Why use it at all? If you use `async/await` there's no need for `BeginInvoke`, `Invoke`  or `InvokeRequired`. The original code shouldn't be using `Invoke` in the first place. It's not just that it was replaced by `async/await`, `Invoke` will *block* if the UI thread is busy. This can lead to deadlock

Comment: @Kaija were you able to figure this out?